# How do I use Ajax to save a cache file?

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, jquery

I have a javascript/ajax function which looks for a json file hosted on another server. I need my function to perform the following actions:

1. Get json file from external server
2. Save json file on its own local server
3. Check to see if json file is older than 1 hr
4. If it isnt older than 1hr then use that data
5. If it is older than 1hr - re-download from external server and overwrite local version

Currently my function gets the data from the external sever everytime it is called. I need to add in this caching functionality but am unsure how to takle it.

Can anyone offer any advise?

Here my code:

```
       function ajaxLoad(page,url,type,variety,category , widgetClickedId)
       {         

            /*
             * Checking the clicked id is the same as passed in one
             * TODO refactor so the clicked id only ever gets passed 
             */
            if(widgetId != widgetClickedId && widgetClickedId != undefined)
            {
                return false;
            }

            var website = $('#button-print'+widgetId).data("website");          
            var page = $('#button-print'+widgetId).data("page");


            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',                   
                url:  'www.myothersite.com/api/v1/productchoice.json?website='+website,
                async: true,
                jsonp: 'callback',
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                success: function(productchoice)
                { 

                    if(productchoice['brand'+widgetId] == 'null' || productchoice['brand'+widgetId] == undefined)
                    {
                        productchoice['brand'+widgetId] = '';
                    }
                    //check that all values are not null , if not , then show the widget                    
                    if(        productchoice['brand'+widgetId] == ''                                    
                            && productchoice['subject'+widgetId] == '' 
                            && productchoice['market'+widgetId] == ''
                            && productchoice['type'+widgetId] == ''
                            && productchoice['bookazinebrands'+widgetId] == '')
                    {                       

                        //is this corect?                           
                        $('#gdmContainer'+widgetId).hide();
                        //return false;
                    }
                    else
                    {                   
                        $('#gdmContainer'+widgetId).show();                         
                    }

                    setRibbons(productchoice.ribbonTop , productchoice.ribbonBottom);
                    getProductChoice( productchoice );    
                    setLoveTitle( productchoice);
                    setDefaultBtn(productchoice['defaultBtn'+widgetId]);                     
                    return productchoice; 
                }               
            });
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

All you'll need to do is create a javascript object with the data that's returned from the Ajax request. As part of that object, store the date of when the object was cached. You can then compare that date with the current time each time you call the function.

Here's how I might tackle this:

```
     // Variable to contain cached object. Make sure it name it better...
     var x = null;

     function ajaxLoad(page, url, type, variety,category, widgetClickedId)
     {
        /*
        * Checking the clicked id is the same as passed in one
        * TODO refactor so the clicked id only ever gets passed 
        */
        if(widgetId != widgetClickedId && widgetClickedId != undefined)
        {
            return false;
        }

        var website = $('#button-print'+widgetId).data("website");          
        var page = $('#button-print'+widgetId).data("page");

        // Creating a new date and adding an hour to it.
        var d = new Date();
        d.setHours(d.getHours() + 1);

        // Test to ensure x is not null and it's not older than an hour old
        if (x != null && Date.parse(x.date) < d) {
            // Do your stuff with the cached file here
        }
        else {
            $.ajax({
                // set up your ajax request
                ...
                success: function (productchoice) {
                    // Make sure to cache the object
                    x.file = productchoice;
                    x.date = new Date();

                    // Do your stuff with the cached file here
                }
            });
        }
     }
```

It would be beneficial to put your normal "success" operations in a separate function to avoid repeating the code. If you do this you'd use the cached variable (`x` in the example code) instead of using the `productchoice` variable (i.e. `x.file['brand' + widgetId]`).